# React js (jsx) ternary operator not working as required

Tags: javascript, reactjs, conditional-operator, conditional-rendering

I've passed a prop - {pov} to a component- Page
I also have two other functional components - VisitorPOV and OwnerPOV
if pov === 'visitor' , I want to render VisitorPOV Component else OwnerPOV Component
Here is what I tried

```js
    function Page({pov}) 
    {
      return (
        <div>
          { {pov} === "visitor" ? <VisitorPOV/> : <OwnerPOV/>}
          </div>
          );
     }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

But what ever the prop is, it is only rendering false part ie. the component after :

Please help!
Thanks

Comment: You already have an enclosing `{}` around the ternary so you are already in a JS expression context rather than jsx. So there is no need to enclose the `pov` variable with an additional set of braces. In fact doing so creates an object with `pov` as the key name and the variable value as the value. Since objects are only equal via identity, this will always result in going down the "false" branch of your ternary. *In short, just remove the curly braces surrounding `pov` in your ternary, and it should work.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You ternary expression should be as follows:

```
{ pov === "visitor" ? <VisitorPOV/> : <OwnerPOV/>}
```

I don't need to explain @Crice did explain it in his comment.